Add Rewrite Rule Not Returning As Expected
I have the following code snippet in WordPress functions.php file:
add_action('init', function() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^explore-destinations\/?(.*)','index.php?tt_destination=$matches[1]', 'bottom');
});

It works great when my url is: https://example.com/explore-destinations/north-america/illinois/ or https://example.com/explore-destinations/north-america/illinois/chicago.   I have a filter that sets the query_vars tt_destination properly and parses it as a query var then builds/returns the page accordingly.  For instance the query var in the second page above is set to: north-america\/united-states\/illinois\/chicago and I am able to use it to direct a proper page template and render the content.
What is confusing me, is the following url: https://example.com/explore-destinations/north-america/ returns blank.  I'm looking for it to return the continent (e.g. north-america).
Can anyone provide advice on what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks in advance.
I have tried various machinations of the regex string, without any success --  e.g. explore-destinations\/?(.*) or ^explore-destinations?(.*)
I've tried rebuilding the permalinks after making the code changes without success.

I figured out the issue occurring.  There is a native re-write rule
[^/]+/([^/]+)/?$

That was taking precedence over my rewrite rule.  This was making it look like an attachment.  I added the following code to functions.php to remove the native rule:
add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array', 'remove_attachment_rewrite_rules' );
function remove_attachment_rewrite_rules( $rules ) {
    // echo var_dump($rules);
  foreach ( $rules as $rule => $rewrite ) {
    if (  $rule =='[^/]+/([^/]+)/?$' ) {
      unset( $rules[$rule] );
    }
  }
  
  return $rules;
}

